# Conditional Berry–Esseen Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem, functional-inequalities

From Wikipedia, the Berry-Essen Inequality is given by
$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|\text{Pr}(X\leq z)-\Phi(z)|\leq \frac{C E(|X|^3)}{E(X^2)\sqrt{n}}.
$$
From a statistics paper that I am reading, I am seeing a conditional analog version of this
$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|\text{Pr}(X\leq z|Y)-\Phi(z)|\leq \frac{C E(|X|^3|Y)}{E(X^2|Y)\sqrt{n}}.
$$
In this case, $\text{Pr}(X\leq z|Y)$ is a random distribution and the RHS is now a random variable rather than a number. This is similar to the conditonal Markov Inequality found in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240246/conditional-markov-inequality).

I would be much appreciated if someone could provide theories or references on the derivation of these "conditional" inequalities. As I am unable to see how they continue to hold once you condition on some sub sigma algebras.

Comment: Possible proof idea: Use a disintegration (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem) to reduce the question to a question about "usual" expectations/probabilities.